# How to copy only directories and it's contents in a folder and exclude level 0 files using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy all the folders in a directory to another directory. I want to exclude level 0 files using batch.

I am developing windows batch script to copy only the folders and their contents. Not the files directly within the parent folder. Is there a way to do this? I tried robocopy and xcopy, but they don't have option to omit only level 0 files. Can I loop over the folder contents and initiate copy only if it's a folder? I am very new to batch, please help. Thanks

Example: I have following directory structure:

Parent Dir:
   Dir1
   Dir2
   .
   .
   DirN
   File1
   File1
   .
   .
   FileN

I want to copy Dir1 to N and their contents including sub-directories,empty folders, etc and skip File1...FileN.

Comment: You may `XCOPY *.* destination /S` all sub-directories and files, and then `DEL /Q destination\*.*` all files in destination level-0 directory only. Or you may do a `for /D` loop over sub-directories only and `XCOPY` their contents...

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me. Thanks for all your help.

for /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b /ad "%pFolder%"') DO (xcopy %Source%%%G %Target%\%%G /e /i /y >nul )